# Usage of "plus occupé que normalement"

Tags: comparatifs

"I'm busier than usual this week."

> 1. Je suis plus occupé(e) cette semaine que normalement/typiquement/d'habitude.
> 2. Je suis plus occupé(e) cette semaine que **je suis** normalement/typiquement/d'habitude.
> 3. Je suis plus occupé(e) cette semaine que **je le suis** normalement/typiquement/d'habitude.

Is it possible to use sentence 1? Or do we have to add "je suis" or "je le suis" as in sentence 2 or 3?

Comment: You can use 1. or 3., or "4. ... que **je ne le suis** d'habitude".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence 1 is correct, but to translate the "than usual" part you should use "que d'habitude", the other options sound a bit strange written this way.

You could also translate it this way

> Je suis plus occupé(e) que d'habitude cette semaine

Or

> Je suis plus occupé(e) qu'à la normale cette semaine

Sentence 3 is ok, but sentence 2 isn't correct.